# Need help with a result of Invariant in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone please help me with this result I saw in M. Artin? It says

Let subspace $W$ of $V$ is a $T$-invariant. $B$ is the bases of $V$. Basis of $W$ is $(w1,w2,.....,wk)$ and $B=(w1,w2,.....wk,v1,....v(n-k))$. $W$ is invariant is reflected in the matrix of $T$ which is denoted by $M$?
Since $T(wj)$ is a linear combination of basis of $W$ and also of $B$ hence coordinates of $(v1,.....)$ will be $0$. It follows $M$ will have block form \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&D\end{bmatrix}.

I am having a hard time understanding how $M$ got this form?

Comment: start by writing down the definition of the matrix of a linear map.  What does the jth column of this matrix tell you?

Comment: I tried that bit I am getting little confused. Shouldn't D=0?

Comment: Why do you think D will be zero?

Comment: Thanks for the help I figured it out.